# Apache Issues on Windows Server 2008

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, coldfusion

I'm looking to reinstall Apache 2.2.25 since I continue to get these errors in the Windows Application log every 2-5 minutes:

```
Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.2.25.0, time stamp: 0x51dd049c
Faulting module name: zlib1.dll, version: 1.2.3.0, time stamp: 0x4790446a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00002bad
Faulting process id: 0x38e8
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfbfd70cdfbc4f
Faulting application path: C:\Apache2\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Apache2\bin\zlib1.dll
Report Id: 745f20de-2bca-11e4-bd5d-002590f28d7e
```

If the new install doesn't work or if there are some "issues", can I simply restore the Apache2 directory from backup and then I'll just be back where I started? I thought about just renaming the current install to something like c:\apache2_old and if something fails, I can delete the new install and rename c:\apace2_old back to c:\apache.

What do you all think?

Comment: Why not totally uninstall the apache you have now and try an install of 2.4?

Comment: We are running ColdFusion 9 and it doesn't support 2.4.

Comment: I tried on my local development to uninstall and re-install the downgraded version of Apache and the httpd.conf file **is** modified so this is very good information to know before hand. Hopefully if someone else reads this, it'll save them a bit of frustration there.

Comment: At this rate, I'll get the tumbleweed badge...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36780 and should have been corrected in httpd-2.2.13 but apparently either resurfaced or wasn't completely addressed.

For now, I'll just comment out the mod in the http.conf file.